# objectMapper with RXCocoa

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

**When i new an model follow by ObjectMapper,just like:**

```
class car:Mappable {
 var color: String?
 var title: String?
 required init?(_ map: Map){
     xxxx 
 }

 func mapping(map: Map) {
       xxxx
    }
}
```

When i want to observe 'title' of car by RXCocoa,just like:

```
Variable(self.car.title).asObservable().bindTo(self.titleLable.rx_text).addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
```

Xcode show error,'Value of type 'String' has no member 'asObservable'',when change 'title' to `title<Variable>` by following RXSwift protocol, The response object car which 'title' is nil.